# htaccess change document root the directory next to current

Tags: apache, .htaccess

My document root is /site/web_123
I want to make it /site/web

I have no access to server configuration, have no ssh access. .htaccess is the only option i can use.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You cannot use a directory outside your current `DocumentRoot`. So you can use `/site/web_123/web` but NOT `/site/web`

Comment: please make this an answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking here is not possible. You cannot use a directory outside your current `DocumentRoot` due to security reasons.

If your current `DocumentRoot` is `/site/web_123` then:

you can use this as virtual root:

```
/site/web_123/web
```

but not this:

```
/site/web
```